# How can I write the SQL-Code, so I only get the first Name?

Tags: sql

From this query
    SELECT NAME FROM OBJ_R

The current output is

```
NAME
--------
Müller, Peter
Mettler, Hans
Casalugi, Maria
```

How to get this expected output:

```
Name
--------
Müller
Mettler
Casalugi
```

And also:

```
First_Name
----------
Peter
Hans
Maria
```

Comment: Store first and last name in separate columns!

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: If you mean the first record, you have to use ths DBMS specific keyword for row index (ROWNUM for Oracle, TOP for SQL server...). If you actually mean the first name of each full name, you'll have to split each full name and again the syntax depends on your DBMS.

Comment: @jarlh how you mean in separate columns?

Comment: Have one column firstname, where you store Peter, and another column lastname where you store Müller.

Answer (score 1):

**[Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) and [MySql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)**

Using SUBSTR with INSTR

```
select CASE WHEN INSTR(NAME,',') > 0 THEN SUBSTR(NAME,1,INSTR(NAME,',')-1) ELSE NAME END as Name from OBJ_R;
select CASE WHEN INSTR(NAME,',') > 0 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTR(NAME,INSTR(NAME,',')+1,LENGTH(NAME))) ELSE ' ' END as First_Name from OBJ_R;
```

**[PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) and MySql**

Using SUBSTRING with POSITION

```
select CASE WHEN POSITION(',' IN NAME) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(NAME FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)-1) ELSE NAME END as Name FROM OBJ_R;
select CASE WHEN POSITION(',' IN NAME) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEADING ' ' FROM SUBSTRING(NAME FROM POSITION(',' IN NAME)+1 FOR LENGTH(NAME))) ELSE '' END as First_Name FROM OBJ_R;
```

**[Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)**

Using SUBSTRING with [CHARINDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp) or [PATINDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_patindex.asp).

```
select case when charindex(',',NAME) > 0 then substring(NAME,0,charindex(',',NAME)-1) else NAME end as Name from OBJ_R;
select ltrim(substring(NAME, charindex(',', NAME)+1, len(NAME))) as first_name from OBJ_R;
```

**MySql**

There's a few other tricks to use in MySql.

Using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,', ', 1) as Name FROM OBJ_R;
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,', ',-1) as First_Name FROM OBJ_R;
```

Using SUBSTRING with [LOCATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_locate.asp)

```
select CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',NAME) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(NAME FROM 1 FOR LOCATE(',',NAME)-1) ELSE NAME END as Name FROM OBJ_R;
select CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',NAME) > 0 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(NAME FROM LOCATE(',',NAME)+1 FOR LENGTH(NAME))) ELSE '' END as First_Name FROM OBJ_R;
```

Using LEFT and RIGHT

```
select LEFT(NAME, LOCATE(', ',NAME)-1) as Name FROM OBJ_R;
select RIGHT(NAME, LOCATE(' ,',REVERSE(NAME))-1) as First_Name FROM OBJ_R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually  @jarlh suggested right option but still this query will give you expected result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1,CHARINDEX(',', name)) AS FirstName FROM OBJ_R
```

Comment: For the OP's concrete names, the part before the comma (the part you're extracting) is the last name, not the first name. The OP wants to extract the first name. Mind you, this is only ever going to work if you can assume that all names are stored in the "(last name), (first name)" format with nothing else in that column, and I suspect that is not something that is safe to assume.

Comment: Unfortunately, these functions may be different from one dbms to another (this syntax looks like SQL server but Oracle uses SUBSTR and INSTR for instance)